Can ingress-nginx-controller work with ipvs?
I am trying to make ingress-nginx-controller work with ipvs.
For this I am injecting:
args:
 - 'ipvs'

Is it a good approach? Can this controller work in ipvs mod at all?
I have made research over internet and on some forums it says it is possible.
But when I apply it it runs with error that there is no argument like this.
